# Spring security jwtAuthConverter not getting triggered

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, keycloak

I am trying to use spring security and keycloak for my auth system in my spring boot backend. The keycloak part is doing it's job, I have a keycloak server running on localhost:8180 where I can creates roles etc. When the backend user is not connected keycloak webview pops up and let me connect or register a new user. When displaying the inide of the OAuth2AuthenticationToken i get every right informations including the role of the user (screenshot 1).

The thing is that when protecting a route with @preAuthorize() (AppController.kt) the hasRole function get's triggered triggering hasAnyRole and hasAnyAuthorityName (screenshot2). But when looking at the roleSet, calling (getAuthoritySet()) I don't see the PREFIX_client_test. When putting a break point in the jwtAuthenticationCOnverter() I see that it only get's triggered on the app startup not when hitting a protected route. I don't know if you have any clue about that, I will provide you the code and screenshot under, thanks for your answers.

Result of OAuth2AuthenticationToken
[Result of OAuth2AuthenticationToken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwZEH.png)

Breakpoint in hasAnyAuthorityName
[Breakpoint in hasAnyAuthorityName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsMMf.png)

**AppController.kt**

```kotlin
package com.linkedout.backend.controller

import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
open class AppController {
    @GetMapping
    open fun hello(token: OAuth2AuthenticationToken): String {
        return "Token: ${token}"
    }

    @GetMapping("candidate")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('client_candidate')")
    open fun helloProtected(): String {
        return "Hello premium user"
    }

    @GetMapping("test")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('client_test')")
    open fun test(): String {
        return "This is a test"
    }

    @GetMapping("admin")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('client_admin')")
    open fun helloProtectedAdmin(): String {
        return "Hello admin user"
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig.kt**

```kotlin
package com.linkedout.backend.config

import com.linkedout.backend.KeycloakLogoutHandler
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationConverter
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
internal open class SecurityConfig() {

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    open fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http.csrf { csrf -> csrf.disable() }
                .authorizeHttpRequests { auth -> auth.anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated() }
                .oauth2Login {  }
                .oauth2ResourceServer { oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt { jwtConfigurer -> jwtConfigurer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter()) } }

        return http.build()
    }



    open fun jwtAuthenticationConverter(): JwtAuthenticationConverter {
        val jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter()
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles")
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_")

        val jwtAuthenticationConverter = JwtAuthenticationConverter()
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter)
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```kotlin
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8180/realms/Linkedout
          jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:8180/realms/Linkedout/protocol/openid-connect/certs
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: backend
            client-secret: PjkVtHOWmu7BEekOqJnY8TopHrJO0iCE
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope: openid
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8180/realms/LinkedOut
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username

server:
  port: 9090
```

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities), authorities mapping in OAuth2 clients is done with a `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` or an `OAuth2UserService`. There is no chance that a `JwtAuthenticationConverter`, or more generally any `Converter<Jwt, ? extends AbstractAuthenticationToken>`, is ever called when you use `oauth2Login` with a browser: inspect your queries with your debugging tools, you won't find an authorization header containing a JWT (you'll just have `JSESSIONID` cookie).

You added both OAuth2 client and resource server configurations to a single security filter-chain. This is a bad idea and leads to the kind of confusion you are struggling with:

- `oauth2Login` is a client concern. It requires **session based security** and as so, should be protected against CSRF: **disabling CSRF protection in a security filter-chain with `oauth2Login` is a serious security breach**. `Authentication` implementation built by such a filter chain is `OAuth2AuthenticationToken`, like you seem having at runtime (or `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` if user is not authenticated)
- `JwtAuthenticationConverter` is used by the default authentication manager for resource server: **when requests are authorized with JWT access tokens** (not sessions) and builds `JwtAuthenticationToken` (not `OAuth2AuthenticationToken`)

You should decide if your security filter-chain is for an OAuth2 client or an OAuth2 resource server and remove the parts that don't match your need.

An application that is solely a REST API should probably contain only resource server configuration. Login and logout shouldn't be its responsibility: this should be handled by the OAuth2 clients querying it (tools like Postman or Spring applications with REST clients like `RestTemplate`, `@FeignClient`, `WebClient` or `RestClient`).

If your application needs to be both an OAuth2 client with login and an OAuth2 resource server, then you should define two distinct `SecurityFilterChain` beans: one with client configuration (sessions, CSRF protection, login and loogout), and another one with resource server configuration (no sessions, no CSRF protection, no login, no logout). This can be needed for instance in a MVC application serving publicly Thymeleaf templates (with `oauth2Login`) and a REST API queried by OAuth2 clients (a MVC controller with a REST client, or any other micro service sending REST request with Bearer Authorization header).

Note that according to [latest recommendations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390), OAuth2 clients (what sends queries to an OAuth2 resource server) should be "confidential", which require it to run on a server you trust. **This excludes SPAs and mobile applications** (which can't keep a secret, reason for it being configured as "public" clients in many tutorials). What can be done for such applications is using a BFF, for instance `spring-cloud-gateway` configured as OAuth2 client with login and `TokenRelay` filter (to replace the session cookie with an authorization header containing the access token in session, before forwarding a request from the frontend to a resource server). Another option is to configure the REST API as an OAuth2 client, but this makes very little sense (why bothering issuing and storing tokens that are never used) and teams with such configuration should probably question their usage of OAuth2 (Form login would probably be more adapted).

For more info and sample configuration, you could find [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials) useful.

Comment: Thank you for your message, it helped me a lot to figure out the problem, but I am still having the issue, i feel like I applied what you said and what was in the advanced doc but for some reason the userAuthoritiesMapper doesn't seem to be invoked, when putting a breakpoint in it it even feels like the class doesn't get instanciated. Maybe I did something wrong here is the SecurityConfig current code : https://pastebin.com/JdgdRnEu

Comment: Your 2 filter-chains are not ordered and none contain `securityMatcher`, so there are great chances that the filter-chain used for your requests is not the one you expect. The filter-chain with highest priority (lowest `@Order`) should contain  `securityMatcher` to define for which requests it should be used, the other one serving as default for requests not matching. This is documented in the tutorials I linked.